# Copy specific lines from text file to create a new one

Tags: matlab

I have created a function that allows copying a number of lines from a text file and create a new file, let's say I want to take only the data contained between `$$ElmLodlv` and `$$ElmNet`.

Here is the code

```
fID = fopen(fileName,'r');

tline=fgetl(fID) ; 

while isempty (strfind(tline,'$$ElmLodlv')) 
    tline=fgetl(fID) ;    

end 

buffer  = fread(fID,Inf) ; 
fclose(fID) ;  
fID=fopen(newFileName,'w');
fwrite(fID, buffer) ;
fclose(fID);  
end
```

The thing is that I don't really know how can I stop my buffer in the line corresponding to `$$ElmNet`, In other words my function creates a new file from `$$ElmLodlv` to the end of the file.
Any ideas how can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about an alternative to `fread(fID,Inf)`:

```
buffer=0;
while ~feof(fID)
    tline=fgetl(fID);    
    if ~isempty (strfind(tline,'$$ElmNet'))
      break;
    end
    buffer(end+1:end+2+length(tline))=[tline 13 10];
end;
buffer=buffer(2:end);
```

Note that `[13 10]` equals to `\n` in the code above.

*hope it helps!*

Comment: Yes it works! this buffer(end+1:end+2+length(tline)) is literaly what I needed. Have a good day sir!

Comment: Glad that I could help. @ssjss7